# JasperReports build report from jar

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jar

Project structure:

war contains:

- Servlet.class
- pom.xml (contains jar as dependency)

jar:

- contains classes which are used in war

Servlet creates A instance and calls method `generate()`:

```
 @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                  HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
A a = new a();
a.generate();
}
```

Then, **method `generate` in A.class** contains these lines:

```
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/foo.jrxml");
    InputStream isSubReport = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/foo_subreport.jrxml");
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(isSubReport);
```

So, when I run this method from project which is jar  - everything is OK.

However, when I am calling this method from war, which has this jar as dependency - I am getting an exception on line

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(isSubReport);
```

What is the right way to call method from jar which will read it's resources and make it work?

**UPDATE:**

**Still no solution**

If I put servlet in same war with reports - InputStream works OK, but if I split them by war and jar - does not works.

It freezes

on line `JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(isSubReport);`

and I have an exception which is surprisingly does not even seen without deep debugging (without debugging no exceptions, white screen) :

```
Method threw 'net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException.toString()
```

this exeption appears here (This is class from jasper-reports lib):

```
 public JasperDesign loadXML(InputSource is) throws JRException {
    try {
        this.digester.push(this);
        this.digester.parse(is);
    } catch (SAXException var7) {
        throw new JRException(var7);
    } catch (IOException var8) {
        throw new JRException(var8);
    } finally {
        this.digester.clear(); // this method works fine
    }
    //this line can not be reached (somewhere appears exception)
    if(this.errors.size() > 0) { ...
```

and to make clear even something - "messageKey" and "detailMessage" of exception :

```
util.message.provider.not.found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by searching through similar questions.

1. You should build jar without any dependencies.
2. Instead of putting them to jar you should add them to war.
3. Build jar and put it as dependency to war
4. build war with jar's dependencies
5. Done

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar file to your web-inf/lib folder and the import the JasperDesign package.

Comment: will try in a few minutes

Comment: wait, I've already imported it. The problem is in inputStream

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Method threw 'net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException.toString()

Answer (score 0):

if the input stream is the problem then try this

```
InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("/reports/foo.jrxml");
```